# How to play a range of songs in python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have written this code which plays music, but it only plays a single song and not all the songs so what changes should I do to play all the songs from a folder, in python,

```
Elif 'play 5 seconds' in query:
      music_dir = "D:\Music\5SOS"
      songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
      print(songs)
      os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
```

And if possible how to play a specific song?

Comment: Are you sure it's uppercase `Elif`?

Comment: `songs[0]` refers to the first item of the list. You will need to loop through `songs`.

Comment: Sorry, its elif, not Elif

Comment: Scratch'N'Purr - Bro can you please tell how to do that ??, if possible